# Add feed to a custom page

Tags: pages, rss, feed

I have searched and found a lot of people asking about how to add a custom rss feed for custom post types/taxonomies. However that's not the problem right now.

I have 2 extra pages on my site that looks like the default index page (with loop and stuff), the only difference is that they have a different orderby. And I want a feed for those pages too. Putting /feed behind those pages returns a Comments feed with no items. How come? The code of those pages are almost identical to index.php and the feed link works fine there.

I understand there's a add_feed function. But I don't want a new feed type, just the default one is fine.

Comment: How have you created these "extra" pages?

Comment: I added two files to my theme folder, Recent-Page.php and QOTD-Page.php, then pasted the index.php code there, created two new pages with those new files as template.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there isn't going to be a feed for those pages, except for the comment feed. Think about it; all that the WordPress Core knows about is the query that gets the page. It does not know what your template code does.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess most people don't make extra pages with different queries. Oh well, guess I'll have to code a rss page from scratch. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MikeNGarret's answer might work, I did not understand it though so I went with an alternative apporach. What I did was make a blank new page template instead, and coded it like a RSS/XML page with my new query.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this would be to add in new rewrite rules for these urls. There are a bunch of different ways to accomplish this, but here's one example:

```
<?php 
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'me_filterRewriteRules' );

function me_filterRewriteRules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $newRules = array();
    // Replace [your-slug] with the slug of your page
    $newRules['[your-slug]/feed/?$'] = 'index.php?feed=rss2';

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $newRules + $wp_rewrite->rules; 
}
?>
```

You'll need to add a new rule with the appropriate related query strings for each page you'd like to add a feed to.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand the code. I tried adding the code to function.php and replacing your-slug with qotd/recent. Couldn't get it to rewrite the feed. Anyway I did a workaround by writing a RSS feed page from scratch.

Comment: You'd have to customize the code a bit more to get it to work. This was just an approach, not a final product. Glad you were able to figure it out.